# How to rerun only failed test cases and get single report for passed and failed scripts in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, report, pytest

I have 25 test scripts in my test suite. When I execute all the scripts, 2 or 3 will scripts will fail every time. If I just re run those failed scripts, it will simply pass.

I am looking for a way to execute all the 25 test scripts and out of it if 2 scripts fail in first go, then only those 2 scripts need to execute again (for 2 or 3 times), before concluding it as fail.

If those 2 fail scripts pass in second go, then I need a html report generated saying all 25 scripts passed.
Is there a plugin to achieve this or some one has faced this issue and succeeded to implement this?

I am using pytest framework and using htmlrunner plugin to generate report.

Comment: You might have race conditions within your tests (tests or data that interfere with the execution of other tests). Sanitize your data so that every test gets it's own, clean data. Don't share data/objects between tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [pytest-rerunfailured](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-rerunfailures/)? It could be used for one specific case as for the whole module or test suite.

For one specific test, you could add next decorator:

```
@pytest.mark.flaky(reruns=5)
def test_example():
    import random
    assert random.choice([True, False])
```

For specify rerun for whole module you could add:

```
# test_some.py
pytestmark = [
    pytest.mark.flaky(reruns=5)
]
```

If you need to specify rerun for whole test session:

`pytest --reruns 5`